# What is proper way to add/remove columns from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception, defaulttablemodel

I've been trying to find answer for this question for two hours already, but couldn't find working answer.
I'm using NetBeans and `JTable`. I need to add or remove rows dynamically depending on value of `JSpinner`.

This is NetBeans' uneditable code:

```
tblPodaci.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Double.class, java.lang.Double.class, java.lang.Double.class, java.lang.Double.class
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex]; //this is line 83
            }
        });
```

This is code that I use to set number of columns:

```
    void spnKValueChanged(ChangeEvent e){
        int k = (int)spnK.getValue();
        if(k == tblPodaci.getColumnCount()){
            return;
        }



      if(k < tblPodaci.getColumnCount()){
          ((DefaultTableModel) tblPodaci.getModel()).setColumnCount(k);
      }else{

          Object[] data = new Integer[tblPodaci.getRowCount()];
           ((DefaultTableModel) tblPodaci.getModel()).addColumn("         ", data);
      }

  }
```

I hide column headers so I don't care about that, I don't need them.
But this code produces `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` when I try to add new row. Exception is thrown after call to `addColumn`, and this is output (only first few lines):

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4   at
>   anova.MainWindow$3.getColumnClass(MainWindow.java:83)     at
>   javax.swing.JTable.getColumnClass(JTable.java:2697)   at
>   javax.swing.JTable.getCellRenderer(JTable.java:5682)  at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCell(SynthTableUI.java:683)

Why is this happening? How can I accomplish what I want? I don't really want to implement my own `TableModel` (which means writing tone of error prone boiler plate code), I'm disappointed in swing already.

I'm not really a GUI person, so I hope you understand. I'm sure that working answer to this question will help thousands of swing developers.

Hope you have answer. Thank you.

Comment: OK, I didn't implement for loop that would add k-tblPodaci.getColumnCount(), but I added just one column. Anyway, question stays the same.

Comment: Using TableColumnModel.addColumn(TableColumn) actually adds column but the same column as the first one.

Comment: you seem to be adding a column instead of a row... you sure?

Comment: Yes, I won't to add a column. I've already made adding new rows automatically when last row is edited.

Comment: [again the same issue, isn't similair...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22812005/714968)

Comment: OK, that worked. Thank you. But that's the reason I don't really like implementing my own subclass. Even NetBeans' developers made mistake here.